# Issue using WITH FUNCTION inside FOR loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, common-table-expression

I am unable to execute the following loop statement:

```
declare
    i number(10);
begin
    for i in (
        with function f(x in number) return number as
        begin
            return x*2;
        end;
        select f(2) r from dual
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.r);
    end loop;
end;
```

I get the following error. Any tips for resolving the issue.

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 23:
PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06550: line 5, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 23:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   loop
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in the WITH clause work in SQL but not in PL/SQL. To keep the SQL statement as-is, you'll need to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare
    type number_nt is table of number;
    v_numbers number_nt;
begin
    --Your original example only returned one row. But since there is a loop,
    --I assume the real code could return multiple rows, so the example was
    --modified to use two sample rows.
    execute immediate
    '
        with function f(x in number) return number as
        begin
            return x*2;
        end;
        select f(2) r from dual union all
        select f(4) r from dual
    '
    bulk collect into v_numbers;

    for i in 1 .. v_numbers.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_numbers(i));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

DBMS_OUTPUT:

```
4
8
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `with function` is a correct syntax in Oracle or SQLServer.

You need to first define your function. try this code -

```
declare
    i number(10);
function f(x in number) return number as
        begin
            return x*2;
        end f;

begin
    for i in (
        select f(2) r from dual;
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.r);
    end loop;

end;
```

Comment: It is valid in [Oracle SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4bdf629bc29456ab62e7ebea75ad7aa7), but not in PL/SQL but declaring a local PL/SQL function is probably better anyway

Comment: Have you ever tried to compile it? `PLS-00231: function 'F' may not be used in SQL`